# Zoom Flickable's content on wheel event

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

By default, `Flickable` scrolls on mouse wheel event: horizontally if Shift modifier is pressed, and vertically if no modifier is active. I'd like to override this behaviour to make it zoom in/out.

I tried to use `MouseArea` as a child of `Flickable`. Defining desired behaviour inside `onWheel` handler I get what I want, but it breaks flicking feature. Motion of two touch points is recognised as a wheel event on my Mac, what prevents `Flickable` to steel this event (`MouseArea.preventSteeling` is `false` by default). So I get somewhat mixed zooming feature that respects velocity/acceleration behaviour of `Flickable`.

Answer (score 0):

Add an onWheel handler underneath your MouseArea:

```
MouseArea
{
               onWheel: {
                   if (wheel.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier){
                       if (wheel.angleDelta.y > 0)
                       {
                           zoomin()
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           zoomout()
                       }

                   }
                   else{
                       wheel.accepted=false
                   }
               }
}
```

Comment: You may also add the usual <code> anchors.fill: parent</code> on the MuseArea to make onWheel have any effect.